# Build gdb 9.2 fails for intel/Linux targeting ARM

Tags: arm, gdb, cross-compiling, gdbserver

Downloaded from [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/download/)

Untarred, mkdir build, mkdir PC, executed...

```
../../gdb/configure --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

returned...

```
../../gdb/gdbsupport/common-defs.h:33:10: fatal error: ../../gnulib/config.h: No such file or directory
#include "../../gnulib/config.h"
```

There was a 'gnulib' package I could install, installed it and it made no difference

Edited ../../gdb/gdbsupport/common-defs.h and found one header include based on gdbserver/gdb.

```
#ifdef GDBSERVER
#include "build-gnulib-gdbserver/config.h"
#else
#include "../../gnulib/config.h"
#endif
```

Go back two levels and there is a gnulib directory but no config.h, ll shows

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user  51507 May 23 15:10 aclocal.m4
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user   2417 May 23 15:10 ChangeLog
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user  69989 May 23 15:10 config.in
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user 743485 May 23 15:10 configure
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user   1625 Feb  8 05:49 configure.ac
drwxrwxr-x  5 user user   4096 Jun  2 14:53 import/
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user    739 May 23 15:10 Makefile.am
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user  58332 May 23 15:10 Makefile.in
drwxrwxr-x  2 user user   4096 Jun  2 14:53 patches/
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user    249 Sep 20  2019 README
-rwxrwxr-x  1 user user   5641 May 23 15:10 update-gnulib.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

So in the process of writing out the end of my question I put two and two together and am just answering so no one else has to go through this.

As you'll notice configure in gnulib is not executable, so first I ran 'chmod +x configure' Before running it I figured I would go back into my build/PC directory to run configure from there to see if that would recursively configure gnulib, but that did not seem to be the case. You will need to execute ./configure inside of the gnulib directory to generate the config.h. I think regardless of you cross compiling or not you want gnulib to NOT have an explicit target, looks like it'll be used solely for the purpose of building GDB.

After running ./configure you'll now notice you have a config.h, yeahhhhhhh! Now go back to your build/PC directory and run make. Guess what? It will now complain about having already configured the gnulib directory and you need to clean up for make to work. "But Joe!", you say, "Won't that remove the config.h we so desperately needed?" "Yes! Yes it will!" So you need to move your config.h elsewhere, execute 'make distclean' inside of the gnulib directory, go back to your build directory, just wipe it out completely because you'll have issues due to the mixed configurations, re-configure yet again, DON'T FORGET TO COPY CONFIG.H BACK INTO GNULIB/, then run make.

All in a days work.

Answer (score 0):

I met exactly the same problem as yours.

My solution is to go to the **../gnulib**, **../gdbsupport** and **../libiberty**, run ./configure with exactly the same arguments, then make.

After doing so, I went back to /gdbserver, it works.

I guess they thought that we would only compile the whole gdb project together instead of cross-compiling necessary components independently.

Answer (score 0):

In my case helped swap two includes here `gdb/nat/amd64-linux-siginfo.c`.

From:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include "common/common-defs.h"
```

To:

```
#include "common/common-defs.h"
#include <signal.h>
```

Hope others won't be suffering on this as I was.